# tippecanoe keeps dropping polygons at mid level zooms

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles, tippecanoe

Is there anyway to stop tippecanoe from dropping polygons at low/mid level zooms while keeping within the 500kb per tile size limit of mapbox uploads for an mbtiles file? We are getting a lot of polygons being dropped. We are not sure what flags to use to make this possible.

This is the command line:

```
tippecanoe -o polys.mbtiles \
--coalesce-smallest-as-needed \
--coalesce-densest-as-needed \
--coalesce-fraction-as-needed \
--simplify-only-low-zooms \
--no-feature-limit \
--no-tile-size-limit \
--minimum-zoom=10 \
--maximum-zoom=20 \
--calculate-feature-density
```

Without `--no-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit,` features get dropped.

Comment: What flags are you using at the moment? Maybe include your complete command line.

Comment: tippecanoe -o polys.mbtiles \    --coalesce-smallest-as-needed \    --coalesce-densest-as-needed \    --coalesce-fraction-as-needed \    --simplify-only-low-zooms \    --no-feature-limit \    --no-tile-size-limit \    --minimum-zoom=10 \    --maximum-zoom=20 \    --calculate-feature-density \

Comment: without  --no-feature-limit \ --no-tile-size-limit, features get dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possible solutions to prevent small polygons being dropped, depending on what the cause of the dropping is.

- Remove attributes you don't need, with `--include`
- Use `--detect-shared-borders` to store polygons that touch each other more efficiently.
- Use `--simplification=10` or higher to reduce the precision of locations.
- Use `--drop-smallest-as-needed` so that the polygons that are dropped are the smallest ones, not randomly chosen.
- Add specific properties onto your GeoJSON objects to specify which ones should not appear at certain zooms

But ultimately, there is a tradeoff. You can't have infinite information within every tile, so you will have to choose what information you do want to keep.